# How to cube a squared answer using Java inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

The directions for our programming activity is this (roughly translated to English):

*Directions: Write a program that will compute the square and cube of a user inputted number. Create classes that show the feature of Inheritance and Encapsulation of Java. Create your own declarations.*

And so far I've already done the squared number. This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Square {

    protected int square;
    
    public int getSquare() {
        return square;
    }

    public void setSquare (int numberToSquare) {
        square = numberToSquare*numberToSquare;
    }  

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Square number2 = new Square();
        Cube number3 = new Cube();
        
        System.out.println("Enter number to square and cube: ");
        int userNumber = input.nextInt();
        
        number2.setSquare(userNumber);
        number3.setCube(userNumber);
        
        System.out.println("The square of " + userNumber + " is " + number2.getSquare());
        System.out.println("The cube of " + userNumber + " is " + number3.getCube());
    }
    
}
```

And this is my Cube class:

```
class Cube extends Square {
    protected int cube;
    
    public int getCube() {
        return cube;
    }
    
    public void setCube (int numberToCube){
        cube = getSquare()*numberToCube;
    }

}
```

I know my setCube is wrong but that's what I would like to ask: is it possible for me to use the squared answer so I can avoid having to type *numberToCube   x   numberToCube   x   numberToCube*?

Comment: This is a weird assignment, but most likely you should be saving the base number (`userNumber`) in the base class using a constructor and have `getSquare()` and `getCube()` methods.

Comment: To answer your question, did you try it?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes, I tried running it and the square output is okay the answer but the cube answer just outputs "The cube of ___ is 0"

Comment: i think you just need to call number3.setSquare(userNumber)

Comment: `Cube.setCube()` needs to call `super.setSquare(numberToCube)` before the multipication. But I think you are being asked to provide a single `int getResult()` method that you override in `Cube`. And I wouldn't have those `setXXX()` methods either: I would provide the value in the constructor and compute the value either there or in the `getValue()` method.

Comment: @user207421 Excuse me if this sounds repetitive but as I understand you: I should put `@Override` in my `getCube()` and change it to `getResult` instead? and I should remove the computations in my `set` methods and put it in my `getResult` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or even a little bit more simple:

```
public class Square {

    // Value is protected, so you can also see it in the Cube class.
    protected int val;

    public Square(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int calculate() {
        return val*val;
    }
}

public class Cube extends Square {

    public Cube(int val) {
        super(val);
    }

    @Override
    public int calculate() {
        super.calculate()*val;
    }
}
```

Either way I think this is a missunderstanding of object oriented programming and inheritance, because you use two classes for some very basic calculations. These aren't any objects, that share attributes in the way that OOP should be used.

Comment: I tweaked your code to fit in mine and it worked! Thank you so much! And yea, I'll be sure to tell my teacher that. I honestly feel lost about the concepts of OOP in Java bcuz he rarely explains them in depth. Do you know any books or websites that can help me?

Comment: hmm...if you can understand german, then I can recommend "Java ist auch nur eine Insel". I do not know a good english book.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your classes like following. (Decorator Design Pattern)

```
public interface Operation {
   public int getResult(int input);
}

public class Square implements Operation{

    public int getResult(int input) {
        return input*input;
    }
}

class Cube implements Operation {
    private Operation operation;

    public Cube(Operation operation){
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public int getResult(int input) {
        return operation.getResult(input) * input;
    }

}
```

And then call above :

```
Operation square= new Square();
Cube cube= new Cube(square);
cube.getResult(input);
```